# Comparing two lists in python and only keeping matches and non matches

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to iterate over two lists of tuples and am looking for matches. I want to generate two lists of tuples as output: one containing matches (tuples whose first value appears in both lists) and one with non-matches (tuples whose first value appears in one list, but not in the other).

I tried implementing this by iterating over the two lists in a nested loop and comparing the tuples there. However, when I do that, the resulting "no match" list also contains tuples that do match, and also appear in the "match" list.

I'm trying to avoid this. There must be a better way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is an example:

```py
data1 = [
    ("Aaden", "3"),
    ("Aamir", "3"),
    ("Aarav", "3"),
    ("aaren", "3"),
    ("aarika", "3"),
    ("Adad", "3")
]

data2 = [
    ("Aaden", "3"),
    ("Aamir", "3"),
    ("Aarav", "3"),
    ("aaren", "3"),
    ("aarika", "3"),
    ("Aaron", "3"),
    ("Abaddon", "3"),
    ("abagael", "3"),
    ("abagail", "3"),
    ("Abatu", "3"),
    ("abbe", "3"),
    ("abbey", "3"),
    ("abbi", "3"),
    ("abbie", "3"),
    ("Abbot", "3"),
    ("Abbott", "3"),
    ("abby", "3"),
    ("abbye", "3"),
    ("Abdel", "3"),
    ("Abdiel", "3"),
    ("Abdul", "3"),
    ("Abdulkarim", "3"),
    ("Abdullah", "3"),
    ("Abduxuel", "3"),
    ("Abe", "3"),
    ("Abel", "3"),
    ("Abelard", "1"),
    ("abigael", "3"),
    ("abigail", "3"),
    ("abigale", "3"),
    ("Abigar", "3"),
    ("Abigor", "3"),
    ("Abner", "4"),
    ("abra", "3"),
    ("Abraham", "3"),
    ("Abram", "3"),
    ("Acacia", "3"),
    ("Ace", "3"),
    ("Achilles", "3"),
    ("Aclahayr", "3"),
    ("ada", "6"),
    ("awdad", "3"),
    ("awad", "3"),
    ("Ainiond", "3"),
    ("Adww", "3"),
    ("james","3")
]

match = []
no_match = []

for item1 in data1:
    for item2 in data2:
        if item1[0] == item2[0]:
            match.append(item1)
        else:
            no_match.append(item1)      

print('First List Count: {}'.format(len(data1)))
print('Second List Count: {}'.format(len(data2)))

print('Match Count: {}'.format(len(match)))
print('No Match Count: {}'.format(len(no_match)))
```

Output:

```
First List Count: 6
Second List Count: 46
Match Count: 5
No Match Count: 271
```

Comment: No Match Count can't be > First List Count + Second List Count right?

Comment: @Nishant he adds the same values multiple times. according to code no match count <= (first * second)

Comment: If this works as expected and you are looking to improve your code, please consider posting this on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use *sets* for this.
You can find the common tuples with the intersection (`&`) of both sets:

```
match = set(data1) & set(data2)
```

And you can obtain the non-common elements with the symmetric difference or equivalently `^`:

```
no_match = len(set(data1) ^ set(data2))
```

---

More on [sets — Unordered collections of unique elements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) in the attached link.

Answer (score 0):

There is: make the two lists into sets, and use set operations. eg

```
s1 = set(list1)
s2 = set(list2)
match = s1 & s2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Set:

```
data1 = set(data1)
data2 = set(data2)
match = data1.intersection(data2)
no_match = data1.union(data2) - data1.intersection(data2)
print('match \n', match)
print('Length of Match: ', len(data1.intersection(data2)))
print('no match \n', no_match)
print('Lenght of no match: ', len(data1.union(data2) - data1.intersection(data2)))
```

Output:

```
no match
 {('Aarav', '3'), ('Aaden', '3'), ('Aamir', '3'), ('aaren', '3'), ('aarika', '3')}
Length of Match:  5
no match
 {('Abdulkarim', '3'), ('Aaron', '3'), ('Abbot', '3'), ('abbye', '3'), ('Adww', '3'), ('Aclahayr', '3'), ('Achilles', '3'), ('abagail', '3'), ('awad', '3'), ('Abbott', '3'), ('Acacia', '3'), ('Ace', '3'), ('Adad', '3'), ('Abdel', '3'), ('Abigar', '3'), ('Abdiel', '3'), ('abby', '3'), ('Abdullah', '3'), ('abbie', '3'), ('abra', '3'), ('awdad', '3'), ('Ainiond', '3'), ('Abigor', '3'), ('Abatu', '3'), ('abbey', '3'), ('Abner', '4'), ('Abduxuel', '3'), ('abbi', '3'), ('james', '3'), ('abagael', '3'), ('abbe', '3'), ('Abraham', '3'), ('Abdul', '3'), ('abigael', '3'), ('abigale', '3'), ('Abel', '3'), ('Abe', '3'), ('Abram', '3'), ('abigail', '3'), ('Abelard', '1'), ('ada', '6'), ('Abaddon', '3')}
Lenght of no match:  42
```

Answer (score 0):

Match and Non-Match items from First List as comparing with Second List

```
match_items1=[]
no_match_items1=[]

for temp_data1 in data1:
    for temp_data2 in data2:
        if temp_data2[0].strip() == temp_data1[0].strip():
            match_items1.append(temp_data1)
            break
    else:
        no_match_items1.append(temp_data1)

output: For Match items [('Aaden', '3'), ('Aamir', '3'), ('Aarav', '3'), ('aaren', '3'), ('aarika', '3')]
        For Non-Match items [('Adad', '3')]
```

Match and Non-Match items from Second List as comparing with First List

```
match_items2=[]
no_match_items2=[]

for temp_data2 in data2:
    for temp_data1 in data1:
        if temp_data1[0].strip() == temp_data2[0].strip():
            match_items2.append(temp_data2)
            break
    else:
        no_match_items2.append(temp_data2)

output: For Match items [('Aaden', '3'), ('Aamir', '3'), ('Aarav', '3'), ('aaren', '3'), ('aarika', '3')]
        For Non-Match items [('Aaron', '3'), ('Abaddon', '3'), ('abagael', '3'), ('abagail', '3'), ('Abatu', '3'), ('abbe', '3'), ('abbey', '3'), ('abbi', '3'), ('abbie', '3'), ('Abbot', '3'), ('Abbott', '3'), ('abby', '3'), ('abbye', '3'), ('Abdel', '3'), ('Abdiel', '3'), ('Abdul', '3'), ('Abdulkarim', '3'), ('Abdullah', '3'), ('Abduxuel', '3'), ('Abe', '3'), ('Abel', '3'), ('Abelard', '1'), ('abigael', '3'), ('abigail', '3'), ('abigale', '3'), ('Abigar', '3'), ('Abigor', '3'), ('Abner', '4'), ('abra', '3'), ('Abraham', '3'), ('Abram', '3'), ('Acacia', '3'), ('Ace', '3'), ('Achilles', '3'), ('Aclahayr', '3'), ('ada', '6'), ('awdad', '3'), ('awad', '3'), ('Ainiond', '3'), ('Adww', '3'), ('james', '3')]
```